# Haskell code littered with TVar operations and functions taking many arguments: code smell?

Tags: haskell, stm, tvar

I'm writing a MUD server in Haskell (MUD = Multi User Dungeon: basically, a multi-user text adventure/role-playing game). The game world data/state is represented in about 15 different `IntMap`s. My monad transformer stack looks like this: `ReaderT MudData IO`, where the `MudData` type is a record type containing the `IntMap`s, each in its own `TVar` (I'm using STM for concurrency):

```
data MudData = MudData { _armorTblTVar    :: TVar (IntMap Armor)
                       , _clothingTblTVar :: TVar (IntMap Clothing)
                       , _coinsTblTVar    :: TVar (IntMap Coins)
```

...and so on. (I'm using lenses, thus the underscores.)

Some functions need certain `IntMap`s, while other functions need others. Thus, having each `IntMap` in its own `TVar` provides granularity.

However, a pattern has emerged in my code. In the functions that handle player commands, I need to read (and sometimes later write) to my `TVar`s within the STM monad. Thus these functions end up having an STM helper defined in their `where` blocks. These STM helpers often have quite a few `readTVar` operations in them, as most commands need to access a handful of the `IntMap`s. Furthermore, a function for a given command may call out to a number of pure helper functions that also need some or all of the `IntMap`s. These pure helper functions thus sometimes end up taking a lot of arguments (sometimes over 10).

So, my code has become "littered" with lots of `readTVar` expressions and functions that take a large number of arguments. Here are my questions: is this a code smell? Am I missing some abstraction that would make my code more elegant? Is there a more ideal way to structure my data/code?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you passing a lot of `IntMap`s instead of a `MudData`? Would the latter be an option? Hard to tell without seeing some code -- can you share a small snippet showing a case where the helper needs so many arguments?

Comment: Yep, that's definitely code smell. Nope, I don't know the right way to fix it.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with TVar but can't you factorize it ? ie remove all the TVar from MUDData, and use (TVar MUDData) where needed ?

Comment: @mb14, that's presumably troublesome because it increases contention.

Comment: @chi The reason he can't pass a `MudData` is the helper functions are pure and the `MudData` has lots of `TVar`s for granularity. The pure helper functions may only be used on subsets of the `MudData`, so adding another data structure (or a type parameter to `MudData`) won't help - reading all the `TVar`s to create that one single structure would eliminate the granularity.

Comment: @mb14 That is an option, but then I would be locking on the entire world data instead of just what pieces are required on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I see, however, adding "granularity" to locks usually quickly endup with  deadlocks.

Comment: @mb14 `TVar`s ensure deadlock freedom, since they can only be accessed in STM transactions.

Comment: @Cirdec Why do these helpers have to be pure? One option could be to pass `TVar IntMap`s (or `MudData` carrying all the `TVar`s) and rewrite the helpers inside the `STM` monad so that they can actually read the data. Maybe with lenses and some applicative syntax one can reduce the `readTVar` boilerplate. (Here I am doing wild guesses, I admit.)

Comment: @chi I misunderstood what you were suggesting. I though you were suggesting the same thing as @mb14. With [a little abstraction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28919284/414413), the helper functions can both be pure, operating on a `MudData` without `TVar`s like @mb14 suggested and be passed the whole `MudData`, `TVar`s and all, like you suggest.

Comment: Very thoughtful question.

Comment: Not directly related, but for writing a MUD you might be interested in using [functional reactive programming](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_Reactive_Programming) techniques or libraries such as [Netwire](https://wiki.haskell.org/Netwire).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this obviously makes your code complex and clutters the important code with a lot of boilerplate details. And functions with more than 4 arguments are a sign of problems.

I'd ask the question: **Do you really gain anything by having separate `TVar`s?** Isn't it a case of [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/61231)? Before taking such a design decision as splitting your data structure among multiple separate `TVar`s, I'd definitely do some measurements (see [criterion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion)). You can create a sample test that models the expected number of concurrent threads and frequency of data updates and check what are you really gaining or losing by having multiple `TVar`s vs a single one vs an `IORef`.

Keep in mind:

- If there are multiple threads competing for common locks in a `STM` transaction, the transactions can get restarted several times before they manage to successfully complete. So under some circumstances, having multiple locks can actually make things worse.
- If there is ultimately just one data structure that you need to synchronize, you might consider using a single [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-IORef.html) instead. It's atomic operations are very fast, which could compensate for having a single central lock.
- In Haskell it's surprisingly difficult for a pure function to block an atomic `STM` or a `IORef` transaction for a long time. The reason is laziness: You only need to create thunks within such a transaction, not to evaluate them. This is true in particular for a single atomic `IORef`. The thunks are evaluated outside such transactions (by a thread that inspects them, or you can decide to force them at some point, if you need more control; this can be desired in your case, as if your system evolves without anybody observing it, you can easily accumulate unevaluated thunks).

---

If it turns out that having multiple `TVar`s is indeed crucial, then I'd probably write all the code in a custom monad (as described by @Cirdec while I was writing my answer), whose implementation would be hidden from the main code, and which would provide functions for reading (and perhaps also writing) parts of the state. It'd then be run as a single `STM` transaction, reading and writing only what's needed, and you could have a pure version of the monad for testing.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful reply. I think you really hit the nail on the head: I didn't base my decision to use multiple TVars on any benchmarking. In truth, my game will probably never have enough simultaneous players to create serious contention over a single lock. Still, I wanted to do things "the best way" and write a server that is scalable. But the "best way" I envisioned ended up biting me. I may have  just learned another lesson the hard way.

Answer (score 21):

The solution to this problem is in changing the pure helper functions. We don't really want them to be pure, we want to leak out a single side-effect - whether or not they read specific pieces of data.

Let's say we have a pure function that uses only clothing and coins:

```
moreVanityThanWealth :: IntMap Clothing -> IntMap Coins -> Bool
moreVanityThanWealth clothing coins = ...
```

It's usually nice to know that a function only cares about e.g. clothing and coins, but in your case this knowledge is irrelevant and is just creating headaches. We are going to deliberately forget this detail. If we followed mb14's suggestion, we would pass an entire pure `MudData'` like the following to the helper functions.

```
data MudData' = MudData' { _armorTbl    :: IntMap Armor
                         , _clothingTbl :: IntMap Clothing
                         , _coinsTbl    :: IntMap Coins

moreVanityThanWealth :: MudData' -> Bool
moreVanityThanWealth md =
    let clothing = _clothingTbl md
        coins    = _coinsTbl    md
    in  ...
```

`MudData` and `MudData'` are almost identical to each other. One of them wraps its fields in `TVar`s and the other one doesn't. We can modify `MudData` so that it takes an extra type parameter (of kind `* -> *`) for what to wrap the fields in. `MudData` will have the slightly unusual kind `(* -> *) -> *`, which is closely related to lenses but doesn't have much library support. I call this pattern a *Model*.

```
data MudData f = MudData { _armorTbl    :: f (IntMap Armor)
                         , _clothingTbl :: f (IntMap Clothing)
                         , _coinsTbl    :: f (IntMap Coins)
```

We can recover the original `MudData` with `MudData TVar`. We can recreate the pure version by wrapping the fields in [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html), `newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a}`. In terms of `MudData Identity`, our function would be written as

```
moreVanityThanWealth :: MudData Identity -> Bool
moreVanityThanWealth md =
    let clothing = runIdentity . _clothingTbl $ md
        coins    = runIdentity . _coinsTbl    $ md
    in  ...
```

We've successfully forgotten which parts of the `MudData` we've used, but now we don't have the lock granularity we want. We need to recover, as a side effect, exactly what we just forgot. If we wrote the `STM` version of the helper it would look like

```
moreVanityThanWealth :: MudData TVar -> STM Bool
moreVanityThanWealth md =
    do
        clothing <- readTVar . _clothingTbl $ md
        coins    <- readTVar . _coinsTbl    $ md
        return ...
```

This `STM` version for `MudData TVar` is almost exactly the same as the pure version we just wrote for `MudData Identity`. They only differ by the type of the reference (`TVar` vs. `Identity`), what function we use to get the values out of the references (`readTVar` vs `runIdentity`), and how the result is returned (in `STM` or as a plain value). It would be nice if the same function could be used to provide both. We are going to extract what is common between the two functions. To do so, we'll introduce a type class `MonadReadRef r m` for the `Monad`s we can read some type of reference from. `r` is the type of the reference, `readRef` is the function to get the values out of the references, and `m` is how the result is returned. The following `MonadReadRef` is closely related to the [`MonadRef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ref-fd-0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Ref.html#t:MonadRef) class from [ref-fd](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ref-fd).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Monad m => MonadReadRef r m | m -> r where
    readRef :: r a -> m a
```

As long as code is parameterized over all `MonadReadRef r m`s, it is pure. We can see this by running it with the following instance of `MonadReadRef` for ordinary values held in an `Identity`. The `id` in `readRef = id` is the same as `return . runIdentity`.

```
instance MonadReadRef Identity Identity where
    readRef = id
```

We'll rewrite `moreVanityThanWealth` in terms of `MonadReadRef`.

```
moreVanityThanWealth :: MonadReadRef r m => MudData r -> m Bool
moreVanityThanWealth md =
    do
        clothing <- readRef . _clothingTbl $ md
        coins    <- readRef . _coinsTbl    $ md
        return ...
```

When we add a `MonadReadRef` instance for `TVar`s in `STM`, we can use these "pure" computations in `STM` but leak the side-effect of which `TVar`s were read.

```
instance MonadReadRef TVar STM where
    readRef = readTVar
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for taking the time to write a detailed answer. I get the general idea, but I'm going to have to study how the abstraction works and play with some code to fully grok this. But this is neat; I would never have thought of this.